# Recursively looping through JSON output in Python

Tags: python, json, loops, while-loop

I have the following json output:

```
{  
   "code":0,
   "message":"success",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "group_id":"12345678901234567890",
         "display_name":"GROUP",
         "description":"Group 1",
         "monitors":[  
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "group_id":"12345678901234567890",
         "display_name":"KK-GROUP1",
         "description":"KK Group 1",
         "monitors":[  
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "group_id":"12345678901234567890",
         "display_name":"KK-GROUP2",
         "description":"KK Group 2",
         "monitors":[  
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "group_id":"12345678901234567890",
         "display_name":"KK-GROUP3",
         "description":"KK Group 3",
         "monitors":[  
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890",
            "12345678901234567890"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I have this definition that should be looping through the JSON output received from a pycurl command and find all groups that start with KK for example and create a list from all the ID's in the respective monitors field to add to another section of a script I wrote. In the above output it should provide 9 IDs (3 from each group) ... For whatever reason it's only grabbing the first 3 monitor IDs.

```
def ReturnedMonitors():
    listOfChecks = json.loads(connectSite('GET',''))
    for i in listOfChecks['data']:
        while i['display_name'].startswith(options.clusterName.upper()):
            return i['monitors']
```

The output from this will be passed into the following:

```
for monitor in ReturnedMonitors():
          putData = 'activate/' + monitor
          print "Activated: " + modifyMonitors('PUT',putData)
```

modifyMonitors is another pycurl definition that will post to a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a generator function with - `ReturnedMonitors()` , you have created it wrongly , when you do `return` it returns from the function, you need to use the `yield` keyword , also, if you need to yield each id in `monitors list separately , you should loop over them and yield separately. Example -

```
def ReturnedMonitors():
    listOfChecks = json.loads(connectSite('GET',''))
    for i in listOfChecks['data']:
        while i['display_name'].startswith(options.clusterName.upper()):
            for x in i['monitors']:
                yield x
```

For Python 3.3 + , you can use [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380-syntax-for-delegating-to-a-subgenerator) to yield all values from an iterable/iterator (called generator delegation) -

```
def ReturnedMonitors():
    listOfChecks = json.loads(connectSite('GET',''))
    for i in listOfChecks['data']:
        while i['display_name'].startswith(options.clusterName.upper()):
            yield from i['monitors']
```

Comment: Thanks Anand, that helped.